# insert into front of queue instead of back

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

For a project, I want to insert ASCII letters at the end of queue and numbers at the front of queue. I know how to insert things at the end of the queue, but I am stuck on the latter.

Here is my enqueue function:

```
void LinkedQueue::enqueue(ElementType new_data)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node(new_data);
    Node *tempholder = head;
    while (tempholder->next !=NULL)
    {
        tempholder = tempholder->next;
    }
    tempholder->next = newNode;
    mySize ++;
}
```

How would I modify this for another function named `enqueue_front`?

Comment: You could use std::deque<ElementType> instead? with push_back() and push_front()

Comment: You want to insert in the back *and* the front? then this isn't a queue; its a specialized *deque*. And you should also have a `tail` pointer in `LinkedQueue`, thereby making both head and tail insertion O(1) rather than the expensive O(n) your current tail insertion employs.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I've never even heard of such a thing. I was supposed to use two separate queue functions to either insert at the front or back of the queue. Thanks for the heads up. I will definitely use that in the future.

Comment: @AustinAllenJulio its a little tricky to manage two of them (both are NULL when the container is empty, both point to the *same* node when the container has one node, and they diverge past that, but always comply with it once the list again has zero or one node). But there are *many* samples that exhibit how to do this across the web, so do some hunting or challenge yourself to figure out how to manage them. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Linked List modification does the trick.

```
void LinkedQueue::enqueue_front(ElementType new_data)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node(new_data);
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;    
    mySize ++;
}
```